# jQuery AJAX - Append new data to table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table which is filled out with by an AJAX call. What I want to do is append any new data which has entered the database, I can't seem to get long-polling to work, but this may be because I am still learning and just haven't done it right, so any help will be much appreciated!

The trouble I am having, is not initially filling out the table but updating/appending it with new data once it is entered into the database.

My PHP:

```
<?php

  DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
  DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
  DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'silent auction');

  $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

  if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());
  }

$arr = array();
$total_owed;
$bidders;

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

if($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        $bidders++;
        $arr[] = $row;
        $total_owed += $row['amount_owed'];
    }
}

echo json_encode(array($arr, $total_owed, $bidders));
?>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getData.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                for(var i = 0; i < response[0].length; i++) {
                    $('#bidders').append('<tr><td>' + response[0][i]['id'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['first_name'] + " " + response[0][i]['last_name'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['table'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['items_won'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['pledges_made'] +'</td><td>' + response[0][i]['amount_owed'] + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary">CLICK HERE</button></td></tr>');
                }
                $('#amount').text(response[1]);
                $('#paymentsTotal').text(response[2]);

            }
        });

});
```

My HTML (Where data is appended to):

```
<section id='bidderTable' class='container-fluid'>
        <h1 class='text-center'>Winning Bidders</h1>
        <table class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope='col'>#</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Name</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Table</th>
                    <th scope='col'>No. Items Won</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Pledges</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Amount Owed</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Invoice</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id='bidders'>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </section>
```

Comment: @bolli I would like to update the table whenever new data is input into the database (without refreshing the page).

Comment: Take a look at websockets, they are the right way of doing this rather than long polling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be updating the HTML table at fixed interval by querying from your database. You are now loading the table only on page load.

You should user `setInterval()` of javascript. You can configure the time as you see fit for the requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
       reloadTable()
    }, 5000); // This will load data every 5 seconds
});

function reloadTable(){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getData.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                // This will clear table of the old data other than the header row
                $("#bidders").find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); 
                for(var i = 0; i < response[0].length; i++) {
                    $('#bidders').append('<tr><td>' + response[0][i]['id'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['first_name'] + " " + response[0][i]['last_name'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['table'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['items_won'] + '</td><td>' + response[0][i]['pledges_made'] +'</td><td>' + response[0][i]['amount_owed'] + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary">CLICK HERE</button></td></tr>');
                }
                $('#amount').text(response[1]);
                $('#paymentsTotal').text(response[2]);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is something I have tried to do. But it will just keep appending everything that is in the database already, I would like to append only new data.

Comment: than you should include the timestamp of the last ajax request, and only return data from the backend that is newer that that

Comment: Please read the extra line of code and comment I have added to clear data before appending fresh data

Comment: @zedling Yes. Ideal approach should be same. But in the OP, the query  to select date is ```SELECT * FROM users```, which returns all the value and not just the difference.

Comment: @SandeshGupta This is working for me, thank you so much!

Comment: @SandeshGupta I seem to be getting two of the first database row. Any help with why? EDIT: I seem to have fixed it by adding `$('#bidders').find('tr:first-child').remove();`

Comment: Try ```$("#bidders > tr").empty();```